# U.S. biplane Identification

Tags: identification

Recently acquired at an antique store without any information.

[image]

Full size photo is at my Flickr site: https://www.flickr.com/photos/photolibrarian/13429182134/

Comment: This might be on-topic at Aviation Stack Exchange as well.

Comment: Post the photo in the post, not a link. Also, this is off topic.

Answer (score 12):

It appears to be a Douglas BT-2B. Here is an example for comparison:

[image: Douglas BT-2B]

The BT-2B was the first production model of the trainer version of the [Douglas O-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_O-2).

The specific plane in your picture is USAAC serial number 31-35. You can see the "35" printed on the tail.

Here is what [Joe Baugher's USAF Aircraft Serial Number list](http://cgibin.rcn.com/jeremy.k/cgi-bin/gzUsafSearch.pl?target=&content=Douglas%20B) has to say about this plane:

> 35 w/o at Bolling Field, DC Feb 28, 1934

This means that the plane was written off (as unrepairable) at Bolling Field in Washington D.C. on February 28, 1934.

It's possible, as pointed out in the comments, that the serial number is actually 31-85, as the tail number is a little blurry. That airframe was written off at Randolph Field, TX on 9/15/1932. [Source](http://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/wiki.php?id=105653)

Comment: Nice ID. The tail number looks more like 85 to me though.  That airframe was written off at Randolph Field, TX on 9/15/1932. http://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/wiki.php?id=105653.

Comment: @Comintern I'll add that in.

Comment: [More information at Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9423/44) - I may revise this answer later.