# Is this a Sherman, and if so what model?

Tags: world-war-two, tanks

A [River Oaks, Houston, TX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Oaks,_Houston), attorney recently purchased and parked outside his home  [a fully functional World War Two tank](https://www.wtsp.com/article/news/local/hoa-fight-over-world-war-ii-tank-in-river-oaks/67-479874785).

*Note: The original newspaper article claimed the tank was "fully functional" - but the main gun was disabled by drilling a hole through it prior to departing France.*

To my untrained eye it appears to be a Sherman, but I am looking for a more expert opinion. Can anyone definitely determine the type and model of this tank, along with any other interesting specifications?

> "The problem is there is no action [the Homeowners' Association] can take," said Buzbee. "They can ticket it or they can try to tow it, but the truth is unless I decide to move it, it's not going anywhere."

[image]

Presumably this is a serial number of some sort.

[image]

I'm not sure what these numbers represent.

[image]

---

More details, with thanks to [called2voyage](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/2732/called2voyage)

- https://www.texasmonthly.com/the-daily-post/complete-story-river-oaks-tank/

Comment: It's a M4 Sherman but the exact sub-type might prove tricky to prove.

Comment: Found info on it, but the quotes are not cited so I don't know if the source is good: https://www.texasguntalk.com/threads/texas-man-parks-sherman-tank-in-front-of-his-house.83171/page-4#post-1647420

Comment: @SteveBird: I'll up-vote every answer that adds to the discovery. If I see any further news on it with additional good images I will post those. It occurred to me that the vehicle ID numbers might help in the discovery, so I excerpted those from the video.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Found another source: https://www.texasmonthly.com/the-daily-post/complete-story-river-oaks-tank/

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The auction details for the tank include the id number, and it matches up with Duke's research: https://www.artcurial.com/en/lot-1944-chrysler-m4a4-sherman-3114-46

Comment: @called2voyage: That last link looks like a key part of any answer, so I haven't added it to the question. As already noted, I will upvote any and all answers that add to the information already known when posted.

Comment: The Texas Monthly picture is of a different model Sherman.

Comment: @kimchilover The photo at the top of the article is an illustration for dramatic effect and not an actual depiction of the tank.

Comment: There's a (probably) exhaustive list of Shermans (Shermen?) with illustrations at http://www.tanks-encyclopedia.com/ww2/US/M4_Sherman.php

Comment: @AmorphousBlob: That sounds like a valuable contribution to any definitive answer (hint hint), rather than a clarification request on the question.

Comment: Woot! Another reputation point, come to papa!  :)

Comment: It is not a "fully functional tank" as claimed in the question. In the newspaper interview the owner stated that "the main cannon was rendered inoperable as a condition of his bringing it to America"

Comment: @user2705196: Thank you - now corrected. I saw that note after writing the original question based on the first newspaper article, and neglected at the time to correct.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It appears from the [auction details](https://www.artcurial.com/en/lot-1944-chrysler-m4a4-sherman-3114-46), that the serial number of the tank is 18688.

The serial number does appear on [this list](http://the.shadock.free.fr/sherman_minutia/data/known_sherman_SNs.html) of known Sherman serial numbers compiled by Pierre-Olivier Buan (who has been cited as an expert on tanks of this era) and others.

The entry identifies the tank's type as M4A4(75), which was manufactured by Chrysler. The registration number entry varies from what's on the tank, but it is marked red, which means unconfirmed and possibly wrong. Randolph Duke, in the Texas Monthly article linked in the question, claims the original registration number was painted over. The notes say:

> Comes from the range target, Salisbury Plain. Previously located at Coleraine, NI, UK and then in Normandy, France

The website with the list of Shermans has more information on [this variant](http://the.shadock.free.fr/sherman_minutia/sherman_types/m4a4/m4a4.html).

> The M4A4 Shermans were equipped with a Chrysler Multibank engine; they have a lengthened welded hull. Only the 75mm version were built in the USA, but the M4A4 was also widely used as a basis for 17pdr Firefly tank by the British Army. The users were : Britain, France, China (Source : Wikipedia).
>
> This variant was only manufactured by Chrysler (7499 units produced).
>
> This tank has a 75mm gun, small hatches (protruding hoods), a 57° glacis and dry ammunition stowage bins. The M4A4s were only produced with the 3-piece differential housing.

There is a little bit more information at that link along with pictures.

Comment: If you like identification questions, you may also be interested in these other answers of mine: [U.S. biplane Identification](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/12236/2732), [Who sold this book in London in the 1930s?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/45489/2732), and on Space Exploration [What is this strange, liquid-cooled tube hanging in a wind tunnel?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35985/58)

Answer (score 12):

There's a (probably) exhaustive list of Shermans (Shermen?) with illustrations at [tanks-encyclopedia.com/ww2/US/M4_Sherman.php](http://www.tanks-encyclopedia.com/ww2/US/M4_Sherman.php).
Disclaimer: A lot of models were so similar that it'd be a bit of a chore to try to match up the pics above with this page, though.

Answer (score 9):

The seams appear to all be welded, not cast, so it cannot be an M4A1, an M4 Composite, or an M4A6, according to the chart on this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_Sherman#U.S._production_history) article.

It's got the 75mm gun, not the 76mm or the 105mm gun, which helps eliminate some models like the M4A3E8.

Also note the protrusions at the top of the front hull.  The front of any of the "Jumbo" variants is flat, so this cannot be a Jumbo.

I think it might be a minor variant of an M4A3, based on the discussion on this [site](http://www.imcdb.org/vehicle_861450-Ford-M4-A3--Sherman--1942.html).  I don't find it super convincing, but I think it's the closest we're going to get outside of scheduling a meeting with the folks at Bovington.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the analysis! Notably, all of these details also fit with Buan's identification of it as an M4A4(75).

Comment: Certainly looks like a M4A4 - the same hull as a Firefly, which matches up with the photos I have taken of a couple.

Comment: The use of [VVSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_volute_spring_suspension) is definitive in discounting M4A3E8.

Answer (score -1):

The numbers in the bottom photo 2nd armored divisions 66th armored regiment. the letter number on the opposite fender are most likely the company and appears to possible be company D the number after the dash would indicate vehicle number 12.

Standard American M4 company
1942 to fall 1944
Company command tank M4
Support tank M8A1 (M5 Stuart chassis with open top turret and 75 howitzer)
3 Platoons of M4s
a Platoon consisted of 5 M4s
so the tank company had 17 tanks plus a couple of soft skinned vehicles.
The M8A1 was intended to provide smoke and indirect HE support. with the introduction of the M4105 in fall 1944 the M8A1 was replaced by the M4105 as supply allowed.